# Issues with passing a variable to a macro

Tags: drupal, twig, drupal-8

I have a menu block that shows 4 links. I'd like to remove the last one if the user has a specific role.

The menu block is created in a specific twig file, and inside a macro, as follows:

```
{% import _self as menus %}

{#
  We call a macro which calls itself to render the full tree.
  @see http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/macro.html
#}
{{ menus.menu_links(items, attributes, 0) }}

{% set role = user.role %}

{% macro menu_links(items, attributes, menu_level, elements) %}

    {% import _self as menus %}

    {% if items %}

        <span class='arrow-down'></span>
        <ul{{ attributes.setAttribute('id', 'edit-profil-nav') }}>
            {% for item in items %}

                {% set item_classes = [
                    'col-xs-12',
                    'col-sm-12',
                    items|length == 3 ? 'col-md-4' : 'col-md-3',
                    item.in_active_trail ? 'active' : 'notactive',
                ] %}

                <li{{ item.attributes.addClass(item_classes) }}>
                    {{ link(item.title, item.url) }}
                </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        {{ attach_library('cnas/responsive-navigation') }}
    {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
```

The major issue I have is that I can't interfere with the macro: I'd like to be able to make comparisons with the `user` variable, but when I dump it while being in the macro, `user` shows null.

I found a lot of stuff while looking for an answer, but I've seen everything and its opposite, so I'd like to know if I can do that, and how

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

`macro's` in `twig` have their own scope. You will need to pass the variable `user` as an argument towards the macro in order to access it.

You could also pass the special variable `_context` to the macro.
This variables holds all the variables you passed towards the template.